# ActiveMerchant ActionView helper initializiation crashes if gem source specified as git, but works if it is default or local path

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, activemerchant

I have a weird bug which depends on how I specify gem in Gemfile.

There is no problems if I use standard gem as

```
gem 'activemerchant'
```

or load it from path as in

```
gem 'activemerchant', path: '/home/alexd/src/active_merchant'
```

but if I load it from **git** as in

```
gem 'activemerchant', git: 'https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant'
```

then following code causes crash on running rspec

**config/initializers/active_merchant.rb**:

```
ActionView::Base.send(:include, ActiveMerchant::Billing::Integrations::ActionViewHelper)
```

**stacktrace**

```
/home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/bundler/gems/active_merchant-09ec2cbcfe96/lib/active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb:8:in `<module:Integrations>': can't convert Pathname into String (TypeError)
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/bundler/gems/active_merchant-09ec2cbcfe96/lib/active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb:5:in `<module:Billing>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/bundler/gems/active_merchant-09ec2cbcfe96/lib/active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb:4:in `<module:ActiveMerchant>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/bundler/gems/active_merchant-09ec2cbcfe96/lib/active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/config/initializers/active_merchant.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `each'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:592:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:9:in `require'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/spec/spec_helper.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/spec/controllers/abuse_report_controller_spec.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/alexd/app/app/spec/controllers/abuse_report_controller_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /home/alexd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@app/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

**Update**

Crash can be triggered by even simple require in **config/initializers/active_merchant.rb**:

```
require 'active_merchant/billing/integrations/action_view_helper.rb'
```

and looks like it cause by path length. If I require module with shorter pathname - it works:

```
require 'active_merchant/billing/integrations/moneybookers.rb'
```

Crash also caused by any module with longer pathname - following crashes too

```
require 'active_merchant/billing/integrations/paypal_payments_advanced.rb
```

Comment: Try as mentioned in this blog post: http://blog.nikosd.com/2011/11/fix-ruby-19-cant-convert-pathname-to.html

Comment: Are you sure that the github version is the same you have form local?

Comment: @fotanus Yes, they are the same.

Comment: Which version you are using , and why you want to add github repo ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the URL for the gem has to be in the format **git**://github.com/username/repo_name
**.git**

So for your example:

```
gem 'activemerchant', :git => 'git://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant.git'
```

From http://bundler.io/v1.3/man/gemfile.5.html

> GIT (:git) If necessary, you can specify that a gem is located at a
>   particular git repository. The repository can be public
>   (http://github.com/rails/rails.git) or private
>   (git@github.com:rails/rails.git). If the repository is private, the
>   user that you use to run bundle install MUST have the appropriate keys
>   available in their $HOME/.ssh.
>
> Git repositories are specified using the :git parameter. The group,
>   platforms, and require options are available and behave exactly the
>   same as they would for a normal gem.
>
> gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"

This works for me in my Rails 3.2.16 app.

Alternatively, it looks like you could use the `:github` shorthand for a public repo:

> GITHUB (:github) If the git repository you want to use is hosted on
>   GitHub and is public, you can use the :github shorthand to specify
>   just the github username and repository name (without the trailing
>   ".git"), separated by a slash. If both the username and repository
>   name are the same, you can omit one.
>
> gem "rails", :github => "rails/rails"
>
> gem "rails", :github => "rails"
>
> Are both equivalent to
>
> gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"

Comment: Hmm... it works for me in my Rails 3.2.16 app, and the reference you mention suggests formatting the URI that way.

Comment: Have you read second sentence of first paragraph your quoted from documentations? I tested it both ways with git:// and https:// but we need to use https:// because one of our developers sometimes is behind firewall. And yes, it doesn't crash if I create new app with exactly the same Gemfile but with only single relevant initializer for ActiveMerchant  and scaffolded code only for models/controllers.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? Could it be syntax? i.e. `gem 'activemerchant', git: 'https://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant'` vs. `gem 'activemerchant', :git => 'git://github.com/Shopify/active_merchant.git'` (the `git:` vs `:git =>`)

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with gem source URL or with syntax of Gemfile. The same Gemfile works perfectly with newly created app.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to ruby 2.x solves this problem but I'm still looking for solution applicable to 1.9.3 as I'm not ready to move whole application to ruby 2.x.